# How to align text vertically

Tags: css, html

i have a text inside the `<aside></aside>` tag and now it is appearing like this

```
This is the text in <aside>
```

I want to make it look vertical like this

```
T
h
i
s

i
s

t
h
e

t
e
x
t
```

i am using this css

code:

```
aside {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #475E80;
    height: 690px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    text-align:bottom;
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: There's no such thing as `text-align: bottom`.

Comment: can you create fiddle for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `word-wrap` property. Your CSS should look like this:

```
aside {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #475E80;
    height: 690px;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CkAFs/1/

You could also use `word-break: break-all` but the above solution is *slightly* better supported by the browsers. Here's the reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=word- (notice that `overflow-wrap` property is the alias for `word-wrap`).

Answer (score 3):

This is a trick

```
aside {
    width: 1px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zu8QQ/

You can wrap your `aside` with a `div` if this code messed up your design.

Answer (score 1):

You have many tricks on this link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-easiest-way-to-create-vertical-text-with-css/

The important in this example is `word-wrap: break-word;`

> Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line. However, word-wrap: break-word is part of the CSS3 specification, and is not compliant across all browsers.

```
aside {  
    width: 20px;  
    font-size: 50px;  
    word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gG9Ds/)</kbd>